# Why is it so abstract?

Tags: theming

Please forgive me for asking an open ended question.

Are there various resources that explain WHY different changes were made? I'm getting used to the idea of YAML and TWIG files. I'm just struggling to understand WHY they moved. I'm supportive of learning a new way.

To me, it seems like they took the old TPL files which were decently easy to understand and replaced them with the alternate syntax from TWIG.

What is the functional/practical benefit? is there something I can read or watch to get it?

Comment: Twig is the most popular templating library for PHP. It’s been around for a long time. It sandboxes templating into variables and simple conditions and does not allow execution of PHP in them. There’s a lot more to it than just renaming the file extension. Twigs fairly easy to understand. If you knew the rendering pipeline before, it’s not that much different on the surface.

Comment: Twig templates look a lot nicer then PHP templates though.

Comment: Twig simplifies accessing PHP objects, so a themer can use these objects without being an expert in PHP. Would be nice though, if Drupal provided more objects. The only one now is `Attributes`. Ideally, all template variables would be objects, not arrays.

Comment: Since you are asking if there are resources you can read, this question is off-topic for us. If you were asking why Drupal is so abstract, the question would be too broad for us. We cannot explain in a single answer what the pro of Drupal 8 are, if not making the answer too long, or copying what the documentation for Drupal already says.

Comment: Also, the pros of using Twig are the same of using Twig in Symfony. There isn't anything specific for Drupal, if not very few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand there are two primary reasons this was done. The first was because people were using templates incorrectly - they are supposed to be templates, not logic files. People were putting lots of logic into the tpl.php files, when any logic should be in a preprocess function. The other reason is that TWIG escapes data, preventing people from putting bad code into a template, making Drupal sites more secure overall.

Comment: I am not sure that using Twig stops developers from putting in a template something that should be in a preprocess function. I find questions asking how to achieve something with Twig, here, and in most of the cases the answer is _You should not do that with Twig, but..._.

Comment: Fair enough. It makes it more difficult. As with anything with Drupal, it can be bypassed.

Comment: I think the rule should be that business logic doesn't belong in the presentation layer, which is in Drupal the theme. You can break this rule in Twig or PHP, so this is not a matter of the language you use.